# What is the word pack in C++ draft?

Tags: c++

What is the *pack* means in the C++ draft standard [[basic]p3](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic#3.sentence-1)? Could you provide some concrete explanation, if cannot be explained in precise term?

> An entity is a value, object, reference, structured binding, function, enumerator, type, class member, bit-field, template, template specialization, namespace, or **pack**.

Comment: Probably a [parameter pack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack)

Comment: @ThomasLang: So it's restricted to only template?

Comment: If a parameter pack is meant, then yes, this appears only in C++11 (and upwards) and only in variadic templates.

Comment: For future reference, the wp has an [index](http://eel.is/c++draft/generalindex). A word search there will usually bring you to the definition of things that pop up in the standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard also has an [index](http://eel.is/c++draft/generalindex) and if we search for *pack* in the index we have the following [entry for pack](http://eel.is/c++draft/generalindex#:pack):

> pack, [temp.variadic]

which leads to [[temp.variadic]p4](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.variadic#def:pack) which says:

> A pack is a template parameter pack, a function parameter pack, or an init-capture pack.
>   The number of elements of a template parameter pack or a function parameter pack is the number of arguments provided for the parameter pack.
>   The number of elements of an init-capture pack is the number of elements in the pack expansion of its initializer.

Comment: do you have any advice about reading the C++ draft, or is that just I think it's hard to understand? Or could you provide an approximation about how long it will take to understand it? Thanks for your answer and reading.